# The value of '' cannot be converted to a number

Tags: coldfusion

I have the following query:

```
<cfset x = 0.125>

<cfquery name="MySummary" datasource="xyz">
        SELECT 
          sum(mycount_int_int) * 2 AS MySummary
        FROM
             [MK].[dbo].[mytable] 
        WHERE
            date_dt  >= '#Start_dt# #Start_time#' AND date_dt < '#Stop_dt# #Stop_time#' 


    </cfquery>
```

And I am getting the following error :

```
The value of '' cannot be converted to a number.
```

The error occured in Line 241

Here is my line 241 which is written below the above cfquery in my code:

```
<cfset Voice1st = Numberformat(MySummary.MySummary * x, "0.00")>
```

Should I do something like the following?

```
<cfset Voice1st = IsNumeric(Numberformat(MySummary.MySummary * x, "0.00"))>
```

Please let me know

Comment: When in doubt look at your data.  Start by cfdumping your query results.

Comment: If your query dump showed one row with an empty string, it means the query returned null.  The where clause of your query looks suspicious in that you are passing strings.  What is the datatype of date_dt and what are the values of the four variables you are passing?

Comment: You should be using `cfqueryparam` with your queries, but like Dan said it doesn't appear you're even constructing your query the way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory.

Maybe there were 0 row?  Check `MySummary.recordCount`

Comment: When I checked that, I got `MySummary.recordCount` as 1 , however, after `cfdumping` variable `MySummary` , I got `empty string`. Does Coldfusion counts empty string as a single value?

Comment: check your sql, it's not returning a number that CF can work with.

Comment: SQL returned NULL . I am wondering why I am getting the `MySummary.recordCount` as 1.

Comment: You are getting MySummary.recordcount = 1 because your query returned one record.  It was a null value which ColdFusion converted to an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Change your SQL to:

```
SELECT 
       isNull(sum(mycount_int_int) * 2,0) AS MySummary
FROM
         [MK].[dbo].[mytable] 
    WHERE
        date_dt  >= '#Start_dt# #Start_time#' AND 
        date_dt < '#Stop_dt# #Stop_time#'
```

**Edit:**

Use the `isNull` function depending upon your DB type. `IsNull()` for mssql, `IfNull()` for mySql (mySql has `IsNUll()` too, but that behaves differently), `NVL` for Oracle.

Comment: isNull() is not a valid function in every rdbms and @Rocky did not specify what he is using.

Comment: fair enough. Modifying the answer.

Comment: Should be using `cfqueryparam`

Comment: *did not specify what [dbms] he is using* True, but the usage of `[dbo]` usually indicates SQL Server (or possibly Sybase).  CFML_Developer - Just FYI, `COALESCE(..)` is a slightly more db neutral alternative. It is supported by most major databases.